# What is the level set of 1D function?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vectors, vector-fields

I have encountered a very strange idea today. My prof claimed that the differential of a function $df$ is the number of level curve crossed by a tangent vector $v$ at a point $p$

I tried to reason this out by setting up a 1D function and counting the number of level curves crossed by tangent vector, but what would be the level set for a 1D function?

Comment: Something's fishy. The differential $df$ is an *integer*?

Comment: Maybe I jogged it down incorrectly, it is either $df$ acting on a vector field or $df$ at a point p

Comment: The problem is that a differential is supposed to be linear with respect to the vectors you plug into it. So it can't always evaluate to an integer.

Comment: I think I might know what your professor means. But first, where is your function $f$ defined? On $\mathbb{R}$? An open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$? A manifold?

Comment: $f$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it is too difficult to understand what it means by crossing level sets I wish to know whether if the idea would be simpler on $\mathbb{R}$ itself

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If $p$ has more than one level curve through it then $f$ is constant near $p$ and $df_p \equiv 0$. (Assuming $f\in \mathcal C^2(\Bbb R^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a function $t\mapsto f(t)$ of one real variable its level sets consist of individual points on the $t$-axis: Given a value $C$ the set $\{t\in{\rm dom}(f)\>|\>f(t)=C\}$ is generically a discrete set of points.

The idea of "number of level curves crossed" is somewhat old-fashioned. But it is easiest to grasp in a multidimensional setting. Assume that we have a function $f: \>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}$. In order to visualize this function on a sheet of paper we can draw its level curves for $f$-values spaced by an amount $h\ll1$ specified in advance. On Swiss topographical maps $h$ is $10$ metres. In zones where $|\nabla f(x,y)|$ is small subsequent curves are far apart, and in zones where $f$ changes a lot within a small distance subsequent curves are very near to each other.

Consider now a point ${\bf p}=(p_1,p_2)$, and draw in your figure a vector ${\bf v}$ attached at ${\bf p}$. The tip of ${\bf v}$ is at the point ${\bf p}+{\bf v}$. How many of the drawn level curves does the segment $[{\bf p},{\bf p}+{\bf v}]$ cross? This number $N({\bf p},{\bf v})$ is approximatively given by
$${f({\bf p}+{\bf v})-f({\bf p})\over h}\ .$$
The difference appearing in the denumerator is well approximated by $df({\bf p}).{\bf v}$, so that we obtain
$$N({\bf p},{\bf v})\doteq{1\over h}\>df({\bf p}).{\bf v}\ ,$$
as claimed by your prof.